# nodejs create/delete local file on windows azure website "local storage"

Tags: node.js, azure

I created a generic nodejs/expressjs app and git deployed to windows azure website (not web role, or virtual machine).

The folder structure is typical of an expressjs app:

```
app.js
package.json
routes/
public/
views/
node_modules/
temp_data/
```

The app can happily create and write files to the `temp_data/` folder using nodejs `fs.writeFile('temp_data\\temp_file',...,)`.

These can't be called "local storage", and not sure about the life time of these files. But as the names pointed out, they are temporary files.

The question is that when I tried to delete these files using nodejs `fs.unlink('temp_data\\temp_file',...)`, after `fs.exists('temp_data\\temp_file',...)`, it failed.

Is that because I have permission to write a file, but no permission to delete a file from a deployed folder?

Comment: Any reason you're not using blobStorage? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Comment: To go into details, this isn't a web app. The final program (node.exe + ..) runs on the local machine (deployed via dropbox shared folder). So it has the privilege to read/write the local file system, fork child_process, talk to device drivers, etc. Windows Azure website is a nice platform to deploy the initial nodejs program for "show and tell". So we choose not to use any of the Azure api.

Comment: @ZheHu, `fs.unlink(path, callback)` callback method gets error parameter. Can you provide that error message - what the actual error is? I never had any issues with `fs.unlink` on Azure Website or Azure Cloud Service. You should be able to delete that file.